# How to play video on QPushButton by PySide6.QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside6

I want to play video on QPushButton, so user can easily preview their videos in my tool. And the reason of I want to use QPushButton is I want to listen clicked signal

Here are what I have tried:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets

class VideoPreviewWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.media_player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.setSource(...)
        self.media_player.setLoops(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.Loops.Infinite)
        self.media_player.play()
        
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        # self.preview_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        # self.layout().addWidget(self.preview_button)
        # self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.preview_button)  Nothing happened
        self.video_widget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.video_widget)
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)  # Black screen

        self.media_player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.print_errors)

    def print_errors(self):
        print(self.media_player.mediaStatus(), self.media_player.errors(), self.media_player.errorString())
        # MediaStatus.BufferedMedia Error.NoError
```

I have read Qt Examples here [Player Example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_multimedia_player.html), but cannot find my mistakes.

Comment: The QVideoWidget must be added to a layout in order to make it visible, just like any other widget. Also, setting the button as video output makes absolutely no sense. If you want to start playing when clicking the button, you have to connect the button's `clicked` signal to `self.media_player.play`.

Comment: @musicamante I'm sorry that I removed layout codes when I post them here... Actually I have added them to layout, but still nothing happened. Another point is I don't want to play video when clicking, I want to draw a line on the video screen when clicking.

Comment: Please don't rush questions, as it makes waste time not only to us, but most importantly to you. Take your time to write a complete question, clarify what you need to do and when/why/how/etc. Note that while it's technically possible to add a child widget to a QPushButton, it's not a normal behavior. If you want to get mouse button press events, then you don't need a QPushButton, you could just subclass QVideoWidget and override it's mouse event handlers (like `mousePressEvent()`). Be aware, though, that drawing over a QVideoWidget is not formally supported, and that's because it acts as a ->

Comment: "container" for the video playback, which, depending on the platform, may be done directly by the OS using overlay (in order to provide hardware acceleration), so any attempt to draw will always be "covered" by the video. The only way to draw over video that is guaranteed to work on any platform or configuration is by using QGraphicsVideoItem within a QGraphicsView.

Comment: Instead of the video, try using QLabel to display text "PLAY" when you click the button. Once _that_ works, try to get it to show video instead of the label.